# Web push notification is not working in react js using firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, push-notification, react-redux

I tried to implement web push notification using firebase into my REact js Project.

**Index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import './App.css';
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {messaging} from "./config/FirebaseConfig"

import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/rootReducer";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(`./firebase-messaging-sw.js`)
    .then(function(registration) {
      messaging.useServiceWorker(registration); 
      console.log("Registration successful, scope is:", registration.scope);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Service worker registration failed, error:", err);
    });
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.register();
```

Above file is the main source file which is located into src folder.
I added **firebase-messaging-sw.js** like as below:

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.4/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.4/firebase-messaging.js");

firebase.initializeApp({
        messagingSenderId: "XXXXXX",
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.usePublicVapidKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  const promiseChain = clients
    .matchAll({
      type: "window",
      includeUncontrolled: true
    })
    .then(windowClients => {
      for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
        const windowClient = windowClients[i];
        windowClient.postMessage(payload);
      }
    })
    .then(() => {
      return registration.showNotification("my notification title");
    });
  return promiseChain;
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  // do what you want
  // ...
});
```

I added request permission code on the amount method of the Main component and it looks like as below:

```
componentDidMount()
{
    messaging.requestPermission()
      .then(async function() {
          const token = await messaging.getToken();
          console.log("token", token)
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
          console.log("d to get permission to notify.", err);
      });
      navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("message", (message) => console.log(message));
      messaging.onMessage((payload) => console.log('Message received. ', payload));

      const fetchOptions = {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Authorization": "key=l9oalOyzXcU-NqCI4LZyVrLuF3X3_4tiOHpMUYK_AxC4G...",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              to:"e56_nKx5Ejm1HyWHKcvZFq:APA91bH-...-nKE9YEILYu7RQBBiyCs_CUo2IC0DX-87cMgmMcYwvYQ1yg0BmqWfAgbbkfPtfzXGGOdzmvxVX2wBlwhnnK5oUxjtXalQ4T5CM7IQOhertbXc",
              notification : {
                "title": "Message recieived from:",
                "body": message,
                "click_action": "http://localhost:3000/",
                "icon": "http://url-to-an-icon/icon.png"
              },
          })
        }
        
        fetch("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send", fetchOptions)
          .then(response =>console.log(response))
          .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Also add the code for **serviceWorker.js** file which is used in **index.js** file

```
// This optional code is used to register a service worker.
// register() is not called by default.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on subsequent visits to a page, after all the
// existing tabs open on the page have been closed, since previously cached
// resources are updated in the background.



const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export function register(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker. To learn more,'
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                  'tabs for this page are closed.'
              );

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

I am running the application on port 3000 and I can see that google chrome will throw the error like :

***Service worker registration failed. I don't know what I did wrong.***

[image]

[image]

Would you please help me to resolve the issue? Also, let me know if you require anything else from me.

Answer (score 1):

1.you should use onBackgroundMessage instead setBackgroundMessageHandler in firebase-messaging-sw.js

2.put

```
        export const initializeFirebase = () => {
firebase.initializeApp({

    apiKey: "***",
    authDomain: "***",
    databaseURL: "***",
    projectId: "***",
    storageBucket: "***",
    messagingSenderId: "***",
    appId: "***",
    measurementId: "G-***"
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();}
```

and

```
export const askForPermissioToReceiveNotifications = async (registration) => {
try {

    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    await messaging.onMessage(notification => {
        console.log('Notification received!', notification);
        message.info(notification?.data?.title + ':' + notification?.data?.body)
    });

    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('firebase-message-sw.js', {scope: "/", updateViaCache: 'none'})
        .then((registration) => {
            return registration;
        }).catch(e => {
        });
    await Notification.requestPermission().then((callBack) => {
        console.log(callBack)
    }).catch(e => {
    });
    const token = await messaging.getToken({
        vapidKey: 'BML-',
        serviceWorkerRegistration: registration
    });
    await //send token


    console.log('token do usuário:', token);
    return token;

} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}}
```

in your firebase.js file

3.call initializeFirebase() and askForPermissioToReceiveNotifications() in index.js before serviceworker.register();

it works well for me ...